# How do I configure OpenCV and Cygwin to work together?

Tags: configuration, cygwin, opencv

I'm trying to configure `OpenCV-2.2.0-win32-vs2010` with `Cygwin` to work together. Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: What is OpenCV, what are you trying to do with it, what didn't work (copy-paste the commands you used and the error messages)?

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is  "a library of programming functions for real time computer vision".

Answer (score 8):

Try building a cygwin port of OpenCV instead of using the windows one.   Go to [Cygwin ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/), follow their instructions & download the "opencv" package (listed under graphics in "setup.exe"), make sure to select the "src?" checkbox.   Build it.   That's it.